# .NET Core 2.0 IViewLocalizer write the key instead of the text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, resx, asp.net-core-localization

I'm currently trying to build in a localizer into my application. After reading the Microsoft Documentation I added all the necessary parts, so it should work in theory.

But on the first startup and reloading the page I only can see the keys instead of the text.

Here is my Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...

    services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

    services.AddMvc()
        .AddViewLocalization()
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

    services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
    {                
        var supported = new[]
        {
            new CultureInfo("en"),
            new CultureInfo("de"),
            new CultureInfo("fr")
        };
        options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en", uiCulture: "en");
        options.SupportedCultures = supported;
        options.SupportedUICultures = supported;
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    /...

    var locOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
    app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

The Resources and Views:

[image: Folders]

In the View:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
...
@Localizer["Views_Contract_my_key_on_this_page"]
```

It's also not working by adding the parameter LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.SubFolder to AddViewLocalization

Comment: Shouldn't you add (the name of) the resource file(s) somewhere in options?

Comment: @Silvermind not so far as I know: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.0#resource-file-naming

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

1. Take a look in the samples from Microsoft: https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/tree/dev/samples/Localization.StarterWeb
2. Clean up your Nuget-Packages

Happy codeing!